# .net icon loss when disassembling

Tags: c#, .net, ildasm, ilasm

I disassebmled application using command "ildasm MyApp.exe /output:MyApp.il", then it generated some resource files and MyApp.il. After it i copied all generated files and .il file into ilasm.exe's folder. After built it using command "ilasm MyApp.il" it generated MyApp.exe file, but with no icon. Help me please to restore icon, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **/resource:** *file.res* to add the icon back using [Ilasm.exe (IL Assembler)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Excerpt from Microsoft:

> Includes the specified resource file in *.res format in the resulting
>   .exe or .dll file. Only one .res file can be specified with the
>   /resource option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! There are no files with .res format, only .resources (after disasm). If i try to use /resource:MyApp.Properties.resources it could not create output file and finish with error code=0x80070714

Comment: Then it sounds like that executable doesn't have a resource file.